# Moving Car on number-line with some constraint. Find which number car can't reach and best way to reach a specific number

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Imagine a car on a number line starting from 0. The car can move in the forward and backward direction with constraint and we have to give instructions to move it either forward and backward:-

The car will start its moves with 1 step and after each move, Car acceleration will be increased by 1.
for Eg.

Car is at 0 in starting
lets say we make car move forward
2. Car will move 1 step forward so now car is at +1

let say we make car move forward
3. Car will move 2 step forward so now car is at +3

let say we make car move forward
4. Car will move 3 step forward so now car is at +6

let say we make car move forward
5. Car will move 4 step forward so now car is at +10

let say we make car move backward
6. Car will move 5 step backward so now car is at +5

let say we make car move backward
7. Car will move 6 step backward so now car is at -1

let say we make car move forward
8. Car will move 7 step forward so now car is at +6

and so on ....

So now the question is if car can go in this manner:- 
1. what numbers are not possible to arrive at?
2. Any algorithm to calculate the minimum number of iterations to arrive at number X?

I have tried a lot to find any pattern and any algorithm by myself and also to find out any solution to this problem on the internet but not getting anything better than brute force solution. Please help !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One can get to any number because `-n+(n+1)=1`, so to get to any `N` one can use `2N` consecutive numbers.
2. Add starting at `1` till you either reach `N` or overshoot it. In the case of overshoot, there are two possibilities:

   1. Overshoot is even, then just change plus to minus for the number which equals to half of the overshoot.
   2. Overshoot is odd, make it even, by adding next number and, if needed, subtracting yet another next number. If overshoot is not zero by now, go to 2.1.

Examples:

- 45:
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55, so overshoot is even, follow (2.1).
  1+2+3+4-5+6+7+8+9+10=45.
- 46:
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55, so overshoot is odd.
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11=66, so overshoot is even, so follow (2.1).
  1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9-10+11=46.
- 12:
  1+2+3+4+5=15, so overshoot is odd.
  1+2+3+4+5+6=21, overshoot is still odd, subtract.
  1+2+3+4+5+6-7=14, overshoot is even, so follow (2.1).
  -1+2+3+4+5+6-7=12.
- 5:
  1+2+3=6, so overshoot is odd.
  1+2+3+4=10, still odd, so subtract yet another next number.
  1+2+3+4-5=5, so overshoot even and zero, no need to go to (2.1).

Answer (score 1):

We should have an `O(1)` solution. Consider the tree:

```
                    0
          -1                  1
     -3         1        -1        3
  -6     0   -2   4   -4    2    0   6
-10 -2 -4 4 -6 2 0 8 -8 0 -2 6 -4 4 2 10

-15 -5|-7 3|-9 1|-1 9|-11 -1|-3 7|-5 5|3 13 (left side, right is a mirror)
```

odd, +even=odd, +odd=even, +even=even,
+odd=odd, +even=odd, +odd=even...etc.

Notice that every level of the tree extends the evens or odds but more importantly, the list is complete and includes both positive and negatives:

Evens:

```
0
0, ±2, ±4, ±6
0, ±2, ±4, ±6, ±8, ±10
```

Odds:

```
±1
±1, ±3
±1, ±3, ±5, ±7, ±9, ±11, ±13, ±15
```

We look for the first appearance of the equal or next higher number that's a last element in one of the rows, which we know an `O(1)` formula for. The number we are looking for is sure to be included in the same level.